# Reducer returning twice, secondly returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am writing code to get category without refreshing as soon as it will be added. but after writing the code it is saying "categories not iterable."

--------------------------------categories.action.js code------------------------------------

```
import axios from "../helper/axios";
import { categoryConstants } from "./constants";

export const getAllCategory = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: categoryConstants.GET_CATEGORY_REQUEST });
    const res = await axios.get("/category/getCategory");
    if (res.status === 200) {
      const { categoryList } = res.data;
      dispatch({
        type: categoryConstants.GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS,
        payload: { categoryList: categoryList },
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: categoryConstants.GET_CATEGORY_FAILURE,
        payload: {
          error: res.data.error,
        },
      });
    }
  };
};

export const addNewCategory = (form) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: categoryConstants.ADD_CATEGORY_REQUEST });
    const res = await axios.post("/category/create", form);
    if (res.status === 201) {
      dispatch({
        type: categoryConstants.ADD_CATEGORY_SUCCESS,
        payload: { category: res.data.category },
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: categoryConstants.ADD_CATEGORY_FAILURE,
        error: res.data.error,
      });
    }
  };
};
```

----------------------------------categories.reducer.js----------------------------------------

```
import { categoryConstants } from "../actions/constants";

const initState = {
  categories: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

const getNewCategory = (parentId, categories, category) => {
  let myCategory = [];
  console.log("Within", categories);
  console.log("Within 2", categories);
  for (let cat of categories) {
    console.log("Outside", categories);
    if (cat._id == parentId) {
      myCategory.push({
        ...cat,
        children:
          cat.children && cat.children.length > 0
            ? getNewCategory(
                parentId,
                [
                  ...cat.categories,
                  {
                    id: category._id,
                    name: category.name,
                    slug: category.slug,
                    parendId: category.parentId,
                    children: category.children,
                  },
                ],
                category
              )
            : [],
      });
    } else {
      myCategory.push({
        ...cat,
        children:
          cat.children && cat.children.length > 0
            ? getNewCategory(parentId, cat.category, category)
            : [],
      });
    }
  }

  return myCategory;
};

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default (state = initState, action) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
  switch (action.type) {
    case categoryConstants.GET_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
      state = {
        ...state,
        categories: action.payload.categoryList,
      };
      break;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-duplicate-case
    case categoryConstants.ADD_CATEGORY_REQUEST:
      state = {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
      break;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-duplicate-case
    case categoryConstants.ADD_CATEGORY_SUCCESS:
      const category = action.payload.category;
      const updatedCategories = getNewCategory(
        category.parentId,
        state.categories,
        category
      );
      console.log("categories", state.categories);
      console.log("Updated", updatedCategories);
      state = {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        categories: updatedCategories,
      };
      break;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-duplicate-case
    case categoryConstants.ADD_CATEGORY_FAILURE:
      state = {
        ...initState,
        loading: false,
        error: action.error,
      };
      break;
  }

  return state;
};
```

--------------------------------------------index.js---------------------------------------------

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addNewCategory, getAllCategory } from "../../actions";
import Layout from "../../components/Layout";
import Popup from "../../components/Popup";

const Categories = (props) => {
  const [categoryName, setcategoryName] = useState("");
  const [parentId, setparentId] = useState("");
  const [categoryImage, setcategoryImage] = useState("");
  const category = useSelector((state) => state.category);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllCategory());
  }, []);

  const getCategory = (categories) => {
    let allCategories = [];
    for (let category of categories) {
      allCategories.push(
        <li key={category.name}>
          {category.name}
          {category.children.length > 0 ? (
            <ul>{getCategory(category.children)}</ul>
          ) : null}
        </li>
      );
    }

    return allCategories;
  };

  const getCategoryList = (categories, options = []) => {
    for (let category of categories) {
      options.push({
        value: category._id,
        label: category.name,
      });
      if (category.children.length > 0) {
        getCategoryList(category.children, options);
      }
    }
    return options;
  };

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const togglePopup = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const handleCategoryImage = (e) => {
    setcategoryImage(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const sendData = () => {
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append("name", categoryName);
    form.append("parentId", parentId);
    form.append("categoryImage", categoryImage);
    dispatch(addNewCategory(form));
    togglePopup();
  };

  return (
    <Layout sidebar>
      <div className="main-content">
        <h1>Category</h1>

        <input
          style={{
            width: "fit-content",
            cursor: "pointer",
            backgroundColor: "#24a0ed",
            border: "1px solid #24a0ed",
            color: "#fff",
          }}
          type="button"
          value="Add Category"
          onClick={togglePopup}
        />
      </div>
      <ul>{getCategory(category.categories)}</ul>

      {isOpen && (
        <Popup
          content={
            <>
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Category Name"
                value={categoryName}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setcategoryName(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
              <select
                value={parentId}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setparentId(e.target.value);
                }}
              >
                <option>Select Category</option>
                {getCategoryList(category.categories).map((item) => (
                  <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
                    {item.label}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
              <input
                type="file"
                name="categoryImage"
                onChange={handleCategoryImage}
              />
              <input
                type="submit"
                value="Save Changes"
                className="save-changes"
                onClick={sendData}
              />
            </>
          }
          handleClose={togglePopup}
        />
      )}
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Categories;
```

------------------------------------------store.js-----------------------------------------------

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default store;
```

[it shows following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz8v5.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. In the function "getNewCategory()" the second parameter "[...cat.categories]" must be replaced with "[...cat.children]". It is because cat does not contain categories instead it contain children.

```
if (cat._id == parentId) {
      myCategory.push({
        ...cat,
        children:
          cat.children && cat.children.length > 0
            ? getNewCategory(
                parentId,
                [
                  ...cat.categories,
                  {
                    id: category._id,
                    name: category.name,
                    slug: category.slug,
                    parendId: category.parentId,
                    children: category.children,
                  },
                ],
                category
              )
            : [],
      });
    }
```